# glDrawElements behavior

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am currently reading an `iPhone OpenGL ES` project that draws some 3D shapes (shpere, cone, ..). I am a little bit confused about the behavior of `glDrawElements`.

After binding the vertexbuffer to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, and the indexbuffer to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, the function glDrawElements is called:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, IndexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

At first I thought this function draws the shapes on screen, but actually the shapes are later drawn on the screen using:

```
[m_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

So what does `glDrawElements` do? The manual describes it as `render primitives from array data`. But I don't understand the real meaning of `render` & it's difference from `draw` (my native language is not english)

Answer (score 1):

The DrawElements call is really what "does" the drawing. Or rather it tells the GPU to draw. And the GPU will do that eventually. 
The present call is only needed because the GPU usually works double buffered: One buffer that you don't see but draw to, and one buffer that is currently on display on the screen. Once you are done with all the drawing you flip them.
If you would not do this you would see flickering while drawing.
Also it allows for parallel operation. When you call DrawElements you call it multiple times for one frame. Only when you call present does the GPU have to wait for all of them to be done.

Comment: So for the above example, I may say that glDrawElements draws to the color buffer bound to GL_RENDERBUFFER, not the screen. Then the call to presenRenderbuffer is used to display the color buffer contents on the screen. Is that right?

Comment: You got it! Usually you also draw multiple times for multiple objects and when you are done you present once.

Answer (score -1):

It's true that `glDraw` commands are responsible for your drawing and that you don't see any visible results until you call the `presentRenderbuffer:` method, but it's not about double buffering.

All iOS devices use GPUs designed around Tile-Based Deferred Rendering (TBDR). This is an algorithm that works very well in embedded environments with less compute resources, memory, and power-usage budget than a desktop GPU. On a desktop (stream-based) GPU, every draw command immediately does work that (typically) ends with some pixels being painted into a renderbuffer. (Usually, you don't see this because, usually, desktop GL apps are set up to use double or triple buffering, drawing a complete frame into an offscreen buffer and then swapping it onto the screen.)

TBDR is different. You can think about it being sort of like a laser printer: for that, you put together a bunch of PostScript commands (set state, draw this, set a different state, draw that, and so on), but the printer doesn't do any work until you've sent all the draw commands and finished with the one that says "okay, start laying down ink!" Then the printer computes the areas that need to be black and prints them all in one pass (instead of running up and down the page printing over areas it's already printed).

The advantage of TBDR is that the GPU knows about the whole scene before it starts painting -- this lets it use tricks like hidden surface removal to avoid doing work that won't result in visible pixels being painted.

So, on an iOS device, `glDraw` still "does" the drawing, but that work doesn't happen until the GPU needs it to happen. In the simple case, the GPU doesn't need to start working until you call `presentRenderbuffer:` (or, if you're using `GLKView`, until you return from its `drawRect:` or its delegate's `glkView:drawInRect:` method, which implicitly presents the renderbuffer). If you're using more advanced tricks, like rendering into textures and then using those textures to render to the screen, the GPU starts working for one render target as soon as you switch to another (using `glBindFramebuffer` or similar).

There's a great explanation of how TBDR works in the [Advances in OpenGL ES talk from WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?include=505#505).

Comment: Even deferred or tile based renderers still double buffers. It's just a different way to create the image. After present the pixel buffer from memory is shown and all draw command are discarded. Say, if you move a gl window around it will do that just fine. Also think about the case where you take a very long time (many frames) to render. The previous frame in the front buffer is still around for display.

Comment: True, but I wanted to clarify that the deferral of rendering work until `present` doesn't have to do with buffering. On a streaming GPU with double buffering, work happens immediately on each draw call, but you don't see it until you swap buffers. With TBDR, GPU work doesn't happen until you call for it to be seen, even if there are multiple buffers involved in getting that work done and posting its results to a display surface.